# php get any of my domain root directory like /home/myhosting/public_html/mydomain

Tags: php, path, dns

I am looking to get a path of any domain or subdomain like `/home/myhosting/public_html/mydomain`.

The function will return `/home/myhosting/public_html/mydomain` once I put `http://anydo.com`. If I put `http://sub.anydo.com` it will return the sub domain path.

From any domain I can use that function and get other domain paths on that server.

```
$doc_root = preg_replace("!${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}$!", '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

only works when I put a server.

Comment: or just work with relative path

Comment: To be honest, I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking.

Comment: suppose i am posting http;//mydo.com i want to get /home/myhosting/public_html/mydo if i put http://mydonex.com should get home/myhosting/public_html/mydonex i have to find out root path of my hosting several domain this way